# Populating ComboBox with Data

Tags: c#

I want to display the items in my database inside the combo box after the radio option is been selected. when i tried this nothing was displayed in the combo box. please kindly help

```
private void chkDetailsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButtonA.Checked)
    {
        OleDbConnection connect = db.dbConnect();

        try
        {
            connect.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Opened");
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
            command.Connection = connect;

            command.CommandText = "Select * from Categories";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                cmbDisplay.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["SeatNo"]);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception in Database" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            connect.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging the code?

Comment: Yes i did, it connects to the database but does not display the items in the SeatNo column

Comment: Is this WinForms or ASP.Net? If you can connect, then what is dt.Rows.Count? You don't appear to be putting any data in the datatable!

Comment: You don't fill your DataTable anywhere. You're creating it, not filling it from anywhere, then trying to get the rows out of it - there aren't any.

Comment: You're also not even executing your `OleDbCommand`...

Comment: @Bridge. How do i do that using Access Database?

Comment: @kunleoladepo Try one of the answers below with example code.

Answer (score 4):

Your try block should resemble the following:

```
    try
    {
        connect.Open();
        MessageBox.Show("Opened");
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connect;

        command.CommandText = "Select * from Categories";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        //Put some data in the datatable!!
        using(OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dt.Load(reader);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            cmbDisplay.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["SeatNo"]);
        }
    }
```

You need to fill your DataTable with data!

You might also consider the following:

```
        using(OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while(reader.Read())
            {
                cmbDisplay.Items.Add(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("SeatNo"));
            }
        }
```

This way you don't even need to use a DataTable; this is a more efficient approach for large sets of data.

As an aside, you may wish to consider using [Using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx):

```
    using(OleDbConnection connect = db.dbConnect())
    {
        try
        {
            connect.Open();
            //MessageBox.Show("Opened");
            using(OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand())
            {
                command.Connection = connect;
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Categories";
                using(IDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while(reader.Read())
                    {
                            cmbDisplay.Items.Add(reader.GetValue(reader.GetOrdinal("SeatNo"));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("An erorr occured:" + ex);
        }        
    }
```

This will ensure your connection, command and reader objects are disposed. This is not appropriate if you intend to hold onto an instance of your connection however as it will be closed AND disposed as soon as your code leaves the using statement.

Answer (score 3):

There is missing filling DataTable dt with datas, which are returned by your sql command.

Comment: I want to get data from access database

Answer (score 1):

try with this code - in your sample you don't bind your table with data, you create new instance of table.

```
$ private void chkDetailsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
 if (radioButtonA.Checked)
        {
            OleDbConnection connect = db.dbConnect();

            try
            {
                connect.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Opened");
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connect;

                command.CommandText = "Select * from Categories";
                OleDbDataReader myReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (myReader.Read()) 
                {
                    cmbDisplay.Items.Add(myReader["SeatNo"]);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Exception in Database" + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                connect.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe this. :D

When are you exactly filling the DataTable with data from DB?
There is nothing in between

`DataTable dt = new DataTable();`

and

`for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)`

Comment: While you're there, you may as well mention that the SQL isn't even being executed either!

Answer (score 0):

you can fill combobox with Datatable :

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Books",con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
            comboBox1.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not filling data in Dataset before attaching try this

```
     if(radio.checked) 
     {
      try 
        { 
         connect.Open();
         MessageBox.Show("Opened");
         OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
         command.Connection = connect;
         command.CommandText = "Select * from Categories";

         OleDbDataAdapter db = new OleDbDataAdapter();
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         db.SelectCommand = command;
         db.Fill(ds);
         for(int i=0;i<ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count;i++)
         {
           cmbDisplay.Items.Add(ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString());      

          }
        cmDisplay.DataBind();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception in Database" + ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            connect.Close();
        }
    }
```